# Merge two linq results and convert into json object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

```
var entity = ctx.CDB.Admin_LookupEntities.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "FlexTriggerEventNudgeEmail");
List<Guid> documentIds = ctx.IDB.DocumentNudgeEmailIntersects.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Document_RecordID).ToList();
```

Above are my two linq results which I neeed to merge and add to mergedata as a json object something like this

```
{
"lookupEntity_RecordId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"DocumentRecordIds":["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
}
```

and add here
mergeData.Add("AdditionalData", "");

Comment: What is mergeData here? Is it a separate class?

Comment: yes it is in a separate class

Comment: I mean what properties are in this class because when you add the above result to this mergeData list then the type of the list should contains both of the above properties that you shared.

Comment: mergedata is a dictionary object. In that object I want to send additional data as a key which will give the above json object.

Comment: Try this: mergeData.Add("AdditionalData", new { lookupEntity_RecordId = entity, DocumentRecordIds = documentIds });

Comment: ok will this work for document record ids  as they are in list? also the above solution will give me result in json? Thanks in advance

Comment: It will work for document records but will not give the result in JSON. You need to the conversion. Let me know if need help.

Answer (score 0):

Add First another List values to first List by using loop.Second list will added in first list.
may be this link will address your problem.
JSON And ViewModel Mapping

https://findandsolve.com/articles/jwt-authentication-in-asp.net-core-aef04bc0467b2-aef0504aae5bd